# Is there a price difference between buying and selling through the Captain's Cabin or the shops

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

In AC4 I can upgrade the ship through the Captain's Cabin, or through a harbormaster's shop. Is there a difference in the prices?

I can also sell goods through the Captain's Cabin, is there a difference in the selling price between shops and the Cabin?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no difference in the prices. Selling prices are the same. And the prices of Ship upgrades are the same.